# Qtip: Content getting displayed before rendering with knockout

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, qtip

My Qtip content is dynamic, its content is set to a div which has elements getting binded dynamically. Since the binding is after the content is fetched, Qtip Content is not getting shown.

```
 <td><a href="#" id="qtipselector_01" data-bind="text: title, loadqtip: true"></a>
          <div id="TooltipContent_01" class="hidden">
            <a data-bind="text: title"></a>                 
          </div>
  </td>
```

I'm using $(element).next().html() for content but html is still not rendered when it is assgined.

```
 ko.bindingHandlers.loadqtip = {
        init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
                $(element).qtip({
                    content: $(element).next().html(),
                    position: {
                        my: 'left center', 
                        at: 'center right'
                    },
                    show: 'mouseenter',
                        hide: {
                            fixed: true,
                            delay: 500,

                            when: {
                                event: 'unfocus'
                            }
                        },
                    style: {
                        tip: {
                          width: 20,
                          height: 14,
                        },
                        width:280,
                        height:100,    
                        classes: 'qtip-light qtip-shadow qtip-rounded',

                    }
                });
        }
    };
```

jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/adi85/kq44S/1/